Modules and headers not removed along with linux-image
Old kernel files are piling up and I would like to remove all but the current version and the two versions preceding it to clear some space.
When I run apt autoremove, the old kernels are not recognized as eligible for removal.
So I took a look at /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove and it seems all linux-image packages are covered by NeverAutoRemove which explains why they are not picked up by apt autoremove. Here's the contents:
APT
{
  NeverAutoRemove
  {
    "^firmware-linux.*";
    "^linux-firmware$";
    "^linux-image-[a-z0-9]*$";
    "^linux-image-[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*$";
  };

  VersionedKernelPackages
  {
    # kernels
    "linux-.*";
    "kfreebsd-.*";
    "gnumach-.*";
    # (out-of-tree) modules
    ".*-modules";
    ".*-kernel";
  };

  Never-MarkAuto-Sections
  {
    "metapackages";
    "contrib/metapackages";
    "non-free/metapackages";
    "restricted/metapackages";
    "universe/metapackages";
    "multiverse/metapackages";
  };

  Move-Autobit-Sections
  {
    "oldlibs";
    "contrib/oldlibs";
    "non-free/oldlibs";
    "restricted/oldlibs";
    "universe/oldlibs";
    "multiverse/oldlibs";
  };
};

I also saw that all of the images, headers, and modules (using Pop!_OS with a linux-surface kernel) are marked as manually installed with apt-mark showmanual | grep linux:
linux-headers-6.0.12-76060006
linux-headers-6.0.12-76060006-generic
linux-headers-6.0.6-76060006
linux-headers-6.1.11-76060111
linux-headers-6.1.11-76060111-generic
linux-headers-6.1.11-surface
linux-headers-6.1.12-surface
linux-headers-6.1.6-surface
linux-headers-6.2.0-76060200
linux-headers-6.2.0-76060200-generic
linux-headers-6.2.10-surface
linux-headers-6.2.14-surface
linux-headers-6.2.2-surface
linux-headers-6.2.5-surface
linux-headers-6.2.6-76060206
linux-headers-6.2.6-76060206-generic
linux-headers-6.2.8-surface
linux-headers-6.3.3-surface
linux-headers-6.3.7-surface
linux-headers-6.4.12-surface
linux-headers-6.4.2-surface
linux-headers-6.4.4-surface
linux-headers-6.4.6-76060406
linux-headers-6.4.6-76060406-generic
linux-headers-6.5.4-76060504
linux-headers-6.5.4-76060504-generic
linux-headers-6.5.5-surface
linux-headers-6.5.6-76060506
linux-headers-6.5.6-76060506-generic
linux-headers-6.5.6-surface
linux-headers-6.5.7-surface-2
linux-headers-6.6.1-surface-1
linux-headers-6.6.10-76060610
linux-headers-6.6.10-76060610-generic
linux-headers-6.6.11-surface-1
linux-headers-6.6.5-surface-1
linux-headers-6.6.6-76060606
linux-headers-6.6.6-76060606-generic
linux-headers-6.6.6-surface-1
linux-headers-6.7.2-surface-1
linux-headers-6.7.6-surface-1
linux-headers-6.7.9-surface-1
linux-headers-6.8.0-76060800daily20240311
linux-headers-6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic
linux-headers-6.8.1-surface-1
linux-headers-6.8.8-surface-1
linux-headers-6.9.3-76060903
linux-headers-6.9.3-76060903-generic
linux-headers-6.9.3-surface-2
linux-headers-surface
linux-image-6.1.11-surface
linux-image-6.1.12-surface
linux-image-6.1.6-surface
linux-image-6.2.0-76060200-generic
linux-image-6.2.10-surface
linux-image-6.2.14-surface
linux-image-6.2.2-surface
linux-image-6.2.5-surface
linux-image-6.2.6-76060206-generic
linux-image-6.2.8-surface
linux-image-6.3.3-surface
linux-image-6.3.7-surface
linux-image-6.4.12-surface
linux-image-6.4.2-surface
linux-image-6.4.4-surface
linux-image-6.4.6-76060406-generic
linux-image-6.5.4-76060504-generic
linux-image-6.5.5-surface
linux-image-6.5.6-76060506-generic
linux-image-6.5.6-surface
linux-image-6.5.7-surface-2
linux-image-6.6.1-surface-1
linux-image-6.6.10-76060610-generic
linux-image-6.6.11-surface-1
linux-image-6.6.5-surface-1
linux-image-6.6.6-76060606-generic
linux-image-6.6.6-surface-1
linux-image-6.7.2-surface-1
linux-image-6.7.6-surface-1
linux-image-6.7.9-surface-1
linux-image-6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic
linux-image-6.8.1-surface-1
linux-image-6.8.8-surface-1
linux-image-6.9.3-76060903-generic
linux-image-6.9.3-surface-2
linux-image-surface
linux-modules-6.0.12-76060006-generic
linux-modules-6.1.11-76060111-generic
linux-modules-6.2.0-76060200-generic
linux-modules-6.2.6-76060206-generic
linux-modules-6.4.6-76060406-generic
linux-modules-6.5.4-76060504-generic
linux-modules-6.5.6-76060506-generic
linux-modules-6.6.10-76060610-generic
linux-modules-6.6.6-76060606-generic
linux-modules-6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic
linux-modules-6.9.3-76060903-generic

So I tried to remove one of the oldest packages manually with apt remove linux-image-6.1.11-76060111-generic:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-6.1.11-76060111-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 250 not upgraded.
After this operation, 12.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 1219145 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-6.1.11-76060111-generic (6.1.11-76060111.202302091138~1675975749~22.04~f771a7f) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.1.11-76060111-generic

This leaves behind the headers and modules packages though. I see they are listed under VersionedKernelPackages in the autoremove configuration, but my understanding is that autoremove should default to keeping only the last couple versions.
Checking the dependencies for the leftover headers and modules shows only a dependency on the successfully removed linux-image package:
user@os:~$ apt-cache rdepends linux-headers-6.1.11-76060111-generic
linux-headers-6.1.11-76060111-generic
Reverse Depends:
  linux-image-6.1.11-76060111-generic

user@os:~$ apt-cache rdepends linux-modules-6.1.11-76060111-generic 
linux-modules-6.1.11-76060111-generic
Reverse Depends:
  linux-image-6.1.11-76060111-generic

What other factors could be playing a role in preventing these packages from being removed along with the linux-image package?

Your kernel packages can’t be auto-removed because they’re marked as manually installed. The whole “keep the running and last two kernels on auto-remove” setup relies on kernel packages being automatically installed through meta-packages such as linux-image-surface and linux-headers-surface; it doesn’t work if they end up being marked as manually installed.
I don’t know why your system has ended up in this situation. To clean it up, you might as well proceed manually:
sudo apt purge '^'linux-{image,headers,modules}-'6\.[0-8]\..*'


Ah, thanks. I just put it together. The headers and modules are also marked as manually installed. So that's why they are not removed when I remove the image package.

I'm also not sure why they are marked as manually installed, but I suspect it's because I used the system's GUI update option in the past. I'm not familiar with its internals, but perhaps a side effect was the packages being marked this way. I will avoid it in the future. Thanks for the regex!
